# Inner Joining 6 tables?

Tags: sql-server

I seem to have a many to many relationship here because I'm running a query with these inner joins -

```
FROM         
dbo.Article 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblCountryOfOriginLanguage 
ON dbo.Article.Country_Code = dbo.tblCountryOfOriginLanguage.Country_Code 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblDepartmentLanguage 
ON dbo.Article.Department_Code = dbo.tblDepartmentLanguage.Department_Code 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblMediumColourLanguage 
ON dbo.Article.Medium_Colour_Code = dbo.tblMediumColourLanguage.Medium_Colour_Code 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblGlobalSizeSystem 
ON dbo.Article.Global_Size_Code = dbo.tblGlobalSizeSystem.GlobalSizeCode 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblGlobalFitSystem 
ON dbo.Article.Global_Fit_Code = dbo.tblGlobalFitSystem.GlobalFitCode
```

And it's resulting in millions and millions of rows when I'm only expecting 700,000.

I'm not too familiar with SQL server, but is there a smarter way of going about joining a primary key from one table to multiple other tables? This just doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: Have  you tried a SELECT DISTINCT?  Are they duplicates or a cartesian product?

Comment: comment out all the joins except the base select. check number count. uncomment 1 join at a time, predicting how many records you will have. once you add a table the defies your predictions, figure out why the join is matching more records than expected. more than likely, you have a bad join condition.

Comment: and better yet, put a where clause to retrieve just one record from the Article table, then it will become very obvious when you add in the extra joins...